# Java 8 Replace two null check with Optional

Tags: java, sonarqube, option-type, nullable

Below is my code which is working as expected. But I need to replace it with Optional.ofNullable

```
if (getFirstData != null && getSecondData !=null {
 ... doing my work here
} else {
  ... doing my else work here
}
```

How can I use `Optionals.ofNullable(..)` to replace two AND null checks?

Comment: Why do you want this? Just because it is possible to use `Optional`, doesn't mean you should use it everywhere to replace null-checks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - to remove Sonar. there is sonar, this method is having 10 if checks like this .. i need to remove '&&' So as to remove Sonar

Comment: It sounds like Sonar is flagging duplicate code, not the fact that you are doing "if" statements to do null checks.

Comment: @Ravi Sonars rules are configurable, and not all rules make sense. Just because a tool tells you to do something stupid, doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bit overkill, but if there's need to check *multiple* values for nulls, it may be done like this *using `Optional`*:

```java
static boolean allNonNullsOptional(Object ... items) {
    return Stream.of(items).map(Optional::ofNullable).allMatch(Optional::isPresent);
}
```

But the same may be achieved with much shorter `Object::nonNull`:

```java
static boolean allNonNulls(Object ... items) {
    return Stream.of(items).allMatch(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just technically what you want can be achieved the following way

```
if (Optional.ofNullable(getFirstData).isPresent() && Optional.ofNullable(getSecondData).isPresent() ) {
 ... doing my work here
} else {
  ... doing my else work here
}
```

But as other commenters have already pointed out, it does not seem wise to do so.